# Why some properties value was changed entity state is `UnChanged` in EF Core 2.2.6

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I use EF Core 2.2.6. I come across one strange. I fetched one entity from DB then I changed one property value. I looked ChangeTraker I see entity state is `UnChanged`. But entity property value was changed. The Most part of stange is that EF create `update query`. Everythink works fine. I would like to learn why it is working like this. my example is following

```
 var person = _unitOfWork.PersonRepository.Get(x => x.Id == 20);
 person.RegUserId=5;
 _unitOfWork.Commit();

public TEntity Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
{
  return _dbset.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you show us the DbContext instantiation code ? And also the PersonRepository ?

Comment: @Selmir There is no strange code in `DbContext`. I updated my question. I showed get method in  'PersonRepository'

Answer (score 0):

EntityState is recalculated only when ChangeTracker.DetectChanges() is called, typically during SaveChanges().